# Using clientscript.registerstartupscript with parameters to call javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

1) I'm having an javascript control created with HTML5 and showing it with div.

```
<div id="<%=this.ClientID%>" style="z-index:100;"></div>
```

The control has a method `init()` to which I need to pass parameters from code behind; in order to initialize it. So this is how I'm doing it:

```
string script2 = String.Format("<%=this.ClientID%>.init({0},{1})", param1, param2);

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "initialize control", script2, true);
```

Is this the right way?

2) What's the difference between setting parameter as `{1}` and `'{1}'`?

Answer (score 1):

a parameter constructed within '' is considered as a string and parameter without '' is considered an object.